# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Returns missing values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am attempting to push data through AJAX to my ASP.NET Web Service, which inserts the data into my DB. However, i am having problems looping through my deserialized list.

Here is my class:

```
       Public Class TimesheetDetails
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Public Property TimesheetID() As String
        Get
            Return m_TimesheetID
        End Get
        Set
            m_TimesheetID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TimesheetID As String
    Public Property LineNumber() As String
        Get
            Return m_LineNumber
        End Get
        Set
            m_LineNumber = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_LineNumber As String
    Public Property ProjectCode() As String
        Get
            Return m_ProjectCode
        End Get
        Set
            m_ProjectCode = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ProjectCode As String
    Public Property Comments() As String
        Get
            Return m_Comments
        End Get
        Set
            m_Comments = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Comments As String
    Public Property SAT() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_SAT
        End Get
        Set
            m_SAT = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_SAT As Decimal
    Public Property SUN() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_SUN
        End Get
        Set
            m_SUN = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_SUN As Decimal
    Public Property MON() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_MON
        End Get
        Set
            m_MON = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_MON As Decimal
    Public Property TUE() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_TUE
        End Get
        Set
            m_TUE = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TUE As Decimal
    Public Property WED() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_WED
        End Get
        Set
            m_WED = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_WED As Decimal
    Public Property THU() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_THU
        End Get
        Set
            m_THU = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_THU As Decimal
    Public Property FRI() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_FRI
        End Get
        Set
            m_FRI = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_FRI As Decimal
    Public Property TOTAL() As Decimal
        Get
            Return m_TOTAL
        End Get
        Set
            m_TOTAL = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TOTAL As Decimal

End Class
```

and the method

```
<WebMethod()>
     Public Function SaveData(empdata) As String
    'WebMethod to Save the data  

    Dim serializeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of TimesheetDetails))(empdata)

    Dim ids As String = ""

    For Each obj As Object In serializeData

        If obj.LineNumber = "0" Then

        Else
            Dim timesheetid As String = obj.TimesheetID
            Dim linenumber As String = obj.LineNumber
            Dim projectcode As String = obj.ProjectCode
            Dim comments As String = obj.Comments
            Dim monday As String = obj.MON
            Dim tuesday As String = obj.TUE
            Dim wednesday As String = obj.WED
            Dim thursday As String = obj.THU
            Dim friday As String = obj.FRI
            Dim saturday As String = obj.SAT
            Dim sunday As String = obj.SUN
            Dim total As String = obj.TOTAL
            Dim noteid As String = "No id found"

            Debug.WriteLine(linenumber + " | " + projectcode + ", " + monday + tuesday + wednesday + thursday + friday + saturday + sunday)


        End If

    Next

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

The data arrives from the AJAX post intact, but when the data is deserialized, some of my values remain the same, but others become null or 0.

Here are the before values, successfully posted:

```
[
 {
  "timesheetid":"86",
  "linenumber":0
  },
  {
  "timesheetid":"86",
  "linenumber":1,
  "projectcode":"12988",
  "comments":" test comment",
  "monday":"7.5",
  "tuesday":"7.5",
  "wednesday":"7.5",
  "thursday":"7.5",
  "friday":"7",
  "saturday":"7.5",
  "sunday":"7.5",
  "total":"52"
  }
 ]
```

and here are the values after the data is deserialized:

```
[
 {
  "timesheetid":"86",
  "linenumber":0
  },
  {
  "timesheetid":"86",
  "linenumber":1,
  "projectcode":"12988",
  "comments":" test comment",
  "monday":"0",
  "tuesday":"0",
  "wednesday":"0",
  "thursday":"0",
  "friday":"0",
  "saturday":"0",
  "sunday":"0",
  "total":"52"
  }
 ]
```

Comment: I think the problem is some properties of *TimesheetDetails* class is different with posted object properties. For example, property in posted object is name *monday*, while in *TimesheetDetails* class, its name is *MON*.

Comment: Hi @Trung Duong, could you please add your above comment as an answer, so i can mark is a resolved? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thanks @Chris. I've added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is some properties of *TimesheetDetails* class is different with posted object properties. For example, property in posted object is name *monday*, while in *TimesheetDetails* class, its name is *MON*.

Comment: Many thanks @Trung Duong, matching the posted object name to the class name worked. Thank you very much!